# Object implementing List deserialized as ArrayList when returned as result (instead of original class) in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization, onactivityresult

I am working on an Android app that lets users scan their contracts using their phone's camera. When I want the user to add a new contract I start an activity that lets them take a number of pictures (which that second activity does by in turn using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent) of different pages of the contract. That seems to work fine and I try to return the completed contract object via `setResult()` and retrieve it in the MainActivity via `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CONTRACT) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK))
    {
        this.contract = (Contract) intent.getSerializableExtra(ContractActivity.EXTRA_CONTRACT);
    }
}
```

However, the `Contract` object is not correctly deserialized, which leads the app to crash with a ClassCastException (in the line where I cast it to `Contract`) when it returns to the `MainActivity`:

```
02-06 23:10:53.891: W/dalvikvm(15398): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41910700)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {myapp/myapp.EndkundenMainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to mylib.model.Contract
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3367)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to mylib.model.Contract
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at de.kreditpruefen.lib.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:232)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
02-06 23:10:53.907: E/AndroidRuntime(15398):    ... 11 more
```

My `Contract` object is just a collection of `ContractPage`s so I declared it to implement `List<ContractPage>` like so:

```
public class Contract implements Serializable, List<ContractPage>
```

Therefore, I think something goes wrong with the serialization and Android serializes my `Contract` object incorrectly as an `ArrayList` which it then deserializes as an `ArrayList` again, which obviously cannot be cast to a `Contract`.

Im rather confused why that is. Had I extended ArrayList, I would have thought that it might be due to the superclass messing up the serialization, but the only superclass here is `Object` and implementing the interfaces shouldn't affect the serialization, should it?

Also, I save the `Contract` object in `onSaveInstanceState()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_CONTRACT, this.contract);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and restore it like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        this.contract = (Contract) savedInstanceState.get(EXTRA_CONTRACT);
    }
}
```

**Shouldn't that cause it to be serialized and deserialized as well? Why does it work in that case but not when I transfer the object between activities?**

*Complete parts of the relevant code below:*

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int REQUEST_CONTRACT = 1;

    private Contract contract;

    public void addContract(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContractActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ContractActivity.EXTRA_CONTRACT, this.contract);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_CONTRACT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CONTRACT) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK))
        {
            this.contract = (Contract) intent.getSerializableExtra(ContractActivity.EXTRA_CONTRACT);   
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

`ContractActivity.java`

```
public class ContractActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final String EXTRA_CONTRACT = "ContractKey";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            this.contract = (Contract) savedInstanceState.get(EXTRA_CONTRACT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_CONTRACT, this.contract);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
     */
    private void setupActionBar()
    {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contract, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
                // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
                // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
                // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
                //
                // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
                //

                Intent result = new Intent();
                result.putExtra(EXTRA_CONTRACT, this.contract);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
                // use finish instead of navigateUp which ensures the same instance
                // of the calling activity is restarted which should cause the form
                // in the MainActivity to retain entered text etc.
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // [...]
    // other methods that add pages to this.contract
}
```

`Contract.java`

```
public class Contract implements Serializable, List<ContractPage>
{
    private List<ContractPage> pages;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -708359261524732081L;

    public Contract()
    {
        this.pages = new ArrayList<ContractPage>();
    }

    // [...]
    // implementations of all the other methods required by the List interface by delegating the method calls to this.pages
}
```

`ContractPage.java`

```
public class ContractPage implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2721152546839021601L;

    private transient Bitmap image;
    private File imagePath;
    private transient Bitmap thumbnail;
    private int thumbnailWidthAndHeight;

    public ContractPage(File imagePath, int thumbnailWidthAndHeight)
    {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.thumbnailWidthAndHeight = thumbnailWidthAndHeight;
    }

    // [...]
    // getters and setters for the instance variables. image and thumbnail are lazy loaded from the imagePath.
}
```

**Update:**

The problem also exists the other way round, when I put a non-null contract object in the extra-data of the intent to start the `ContractActivity`. In that case it fails in the same way, when trying to retrieve the contact object from the extra-data and casting it to a contract, which fails because the object is actually an `ArrayList`. So at least in that case it is consistent.